# TVirtualStringTree - cannot make column headers appear as "buttons"

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tvirtualstringtree

I'll preface this by saying I'm fairly new to using `TVirtualStringTree (in Delphi 7)` and I'm learning as I go... fumbling my way along. I'm stuck on how to get my column header `sections` to appear as buttons (thick or otherwise). They seem to want to appear only as "plates" no matter what I specify for the `HEADER.STYLE` property. Yet, I can set them to "Allow Click" with no problem - that works.

I'm using TVirtualStringTree in a pretty basic way - just reading a file from disk, displaying the first 50 records, and then allowing the user to choose a field delimiter (comma, etc)... then showing the resulting fields. Kind of like the little "preview" area when you import a text file into Excel.

I thought before I bombarded everyone with piles of code, someone might know off the top of their head of an obvious and egregious setting or such, that newbies famously overlook. That is entirely possible on my part. Here are a couple of screenshots, however... one of the Header settings in the Object Inspector, and also a run-time shot of my VirtualStringTree.

Screenshot of VST:

[image: Screenshot of VST]

Object Inspector Header settings:

[image: Object Inspector Header settings]